# Yandex Maps рисует карту дважды

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Я делаю сайт, на котором отображается карта (сам сайт на React). Компонент выглядит следующим образом:

```
import { YMaps, Map, Polygon, SearchControl } from 'react-yandex-maps';
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

const Maps = () => (
    <YMaps>
        <div style={{width: '100%', position: 'relative', margin: '100px 0 0 0' }}>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', margin: '0 0 300px 0', height: { xs:500, md: 700 }}}>
                <Map width='90%' defaultState={{ center: [55.758493, 37.839271], zoom: 9, controls: [] }}>
                    <Polygon
                        geometry={[...
                    }}/>
                    <Polygon
                        geometry={[...
                    }}/>
                </Map>
            </Box>
        </div>
    </YMaps>
)

export default Maps
```

Данный компонент я вставляю внутрь другого:

```
<Box className={styles.map}>
    <Maps />
</Box>
```

Собственно проблема: Карта вставляется 2 раза (на скрине). Природа этого явления и как его исправить я не понимаю, так что буду благодарен любым подсказкам.[image: карта вставилась дважды]

Comment: Что еще более странно, первая карта вставляется без полигонов, а вторая с ними

Comment: Скажу заранее, блок <Box className={styles.map}> не имеет стилей в CSS, так что он вряд ли что-то рушит

Comment: Буквально только что отвечал на похожий вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416269 render компоненты повторяется несколько раз, 1й раз до загрузки чего либо 2й раз когда в компоненту попадают данные, не важно от куда. Перед return <YMaps/> просто банально поставь `console.log("Hello, World!");` и в консоли чудесным способов увидишь `Hello, World!` дважды. Сделай debounce для загрузчика карты. А ещё лучше загрузи её через useRef и юзай ref

Comment: Именно поэтому я ненавижу чёртов реакт, его поведение заставляет программистов страдать. А потом страдать фигнёй и вставлять костыли.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8s01ThR7bQ

Comment: Если кому-то интересно, с двойным рендерингом я так разобраться и не смог: пропы в компоненты не передавал, ничего подвоха не предвещало. Решил проблему тем, что поставил strictMode: false в next-config. Аналогично решается для React, нужно убрать React.StrictMode. Костыли - скажете вы. Но это работает, парирую я

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте пакет `@pbe/react-yandex-maps` он совместим с оригинальным `react-yandex-maps` и проблема двойного рендера карты в strict mode решена из коробки.

Answer (score 1):

Яркий пример, простейший компонент имеет простейшую пустую пропсу на борту.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function App(props) {

    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => console.log(progress), [progress]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (progress !== 0) return;
        setTimeout(() => setProgress(1), 1000);
    }, [progress]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (progress !== 1) return;
        setTimeout(() => setProgress(2), 1000);
    }, [progress]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (progress !== 2) return;
        setTimeout(() => setProgress(3), 1000);
    }, [progress]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (progress !== 3) return;
        setTimeout(() => setProgress("Loaded..."), 1000);
    }, [progress]);

    if (progress === 3) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    if (progress === 2) return <h1>Loading..</h1>;
    if (progress === 1) return <h1>Loading.</h1>;
    if (!progress) return <h1>Loading</h1>;
    return <>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <pre><code>{progress}</code></pre>
    </>;
}
```

```
main().catch(console.error);
async function main() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
    root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App today="" />
        </React.StrictMode>);
```

Что нам выводит console.log

```
App.jsx:7 0
App.jsx:7 0
App.jsx:7 1
App.jsx:7 2
App.jsx:7 3
App.jsx:7 Loaded...
```

**Опа-на.... От куда-то два чёртовых нуля.** От куда-же они взялись? 1й раз компонента выгрузилась с пустой пропсой, второй - уже с props.today равной пустой строке.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял ошибку, но можно чуть более конкретно про то, как в подобной ситуации использовать useRef?

Comment: Вот честно, не знаю как быть именно с картой, я бы грузил её без пропсов, как в примере который написал @EzioMercer в ответе, что-бы избежать второго рендеринга. Или загрузил совершенно отдельно от компоненты в reference, и юазл-бы именно референс, а не саму карту.

Comment: Тут сама суть в чём, если у компоненты есть любые пропсы, значит компонента уже динамическая, что накладывает на неё полный перечень ограничений работы со статикой. А yamap насколько я знаю грузится именно статикой.

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно ваш пример воспроизвести не удалось, т.к. вставляется карта только 1 раз. Возможно у вас есть что-то ещё, что может повлиять на кол-во отображения карты

Воспроизводил код без полинонов т.к. не знаю данных:

```js
const { YMaps, Map, Polygon, SearchControl } = ReactYandexMaps;
const { Box } = MaterialUI;

const Maps = () => (
    <YMaps>
        <div style={{width: '100%', position: 'relative', margin: '100px 0 0 0' }}>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', margin: '0 0 300px 0', height: { xs:500, md: 700 }}}>
                <Map width='90%' defaultState={{ center: [55.758493, 37.839271], zoom: 9, controls: [] }}>
                </Map>
            </Box>
        </div>
    </YMaps>
)

const App = () => {
  return <Maps />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-yandex-maps/dist/production/react-yandex-maps.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

А вот и HTML, где явно видно что карта была вставлена только 1 раз:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой, причем на прошлом проекте все работает хорошо.
Решил проблему откатом react и react-dom на более раннюю версию.

"react": "^17.0.2",

"react-dom": "^17.0.2"

проблема ушла.

Comment: нашел еще одно решение: проблема в <React.StrictMode> (index.js) если его убрать карта больше не рендерит два раза. Цитата автора (Антон Горецкий): "Он вызывает установку всех состояний дважды, чтобы выявить возможные сайд эффекты" // источник https://qna.habr.com/q/1152370

Answer (score 0):

решается с помощью ввода в консоль

```
npm run build
и
npm run start
```